# dnf downgrade won't remain on udpate

Tags: fedora, dnf

Somehow I got vlc3.x installed on my Fedora 25, it is not working at all.

I found I could downgrade the package to 2.x,

```
sudo dnf downgrade vlc --allowerasing -y
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'phnxrbrn-evopop', désactivation.
Vérification de l'expiration des métadonnées effectuée il y a 1:59:20 sur Mon Apr 17 22:27:33 2017.
Dépendances résolues.
===============================================================================================================================
 Package                                   Architecture    Version                       Dépôt                           Taille
===============================================================================================================================
Installation de:
 gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free               x86_64          1.10.4-1.fc25                 updates                         1.8 M
 gstreamer1-plugins-bad-freeworld          x86_64          1.10.4-1.fc25                 rpmfusion-free-updates          193 k
 live555                                   x86_64          2016.10.21-1.fc25             rpmfusion-free                  360 k
Suppression:
 gstreamer1-plugins-bad                    x86_64          1:1.10.4-2.fc25               @fedora-multimedia              7.4 M
 live555-libs                              x86_64          1:2016.11.06-2.fc25           @fedora-multimedia              1.2 M
Retour à la version précédente:
 ffmpeg-libs                               x86_64          3.1.7-1.fc25                  rpmfusion-free-updates          6.0 M
 vlc                                       x86_64          3.0.0-0.16.fc25               rpmfusion-free-updates          1.8 M
 vlc-core                                  x86_64          3.0.0-0.16.fc25               rpmfusion-free-updates          7.9 M
 x265                                      x86_64          1.9-3.fc25                    rpmfusion-free                   42 k
 x265-libs                                 x86_64          1.9-3.fc25                    rpmfusion-free                  557 k

Résumé de la transaction
===============================================================================================================================
Installation                    3 Paquets
Supprimer                       2 Paquets
Retour à la version précédente  5 Paquets
...
```

But now if i run an update, that will also update vlc.

```
$ sudo dnf update
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'phnxrbrn-evopop', désactivation.
Vérification de l'expiration des métadonnées effectuée il y a 2:02:35 sur Mon Apr 17 22:27:33 2017.
Dépendances résolues.
===============================================================================================================================
 Package                         Architecture    Version                                      Dépôt                      Taille
===============================================================================================================================
Installation de:
 gstreamer1-plugins-bad          x86_64          1:1.10.4-2.fc25                              fedora-multimedia          2.3 M
     replacing  gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free.x86_64 1.10.4-1.fc25
     replacing  gstreamer1-plugins-bad-freeworld.x86_64 1.10.4-1.fc25
 live555-libs                    x86_64          1:2016.11.06-2.fc25                          fedora-multimedia          368 k
     replacing  live555.x86_64 2016.10.21-1.fc25
Mise à jour:
 ffmpeg-libs                     x86_64          1:3.2.4-2.fc25                               fedora-multimedia          6.2 M
 vlc                             x86_64          1:3.0.0-18.20170322git9513f34.fc25           fedora-multimedia          1.5 M
 vlc-core                        x86_64          1:3.0.0-18.20170322git9513f34.fc25           fedora-multimedia          8.6 M
 x265                            x86_64          1:2.3-2.fc25                                 fedora-multimedia           42 k
 x265-libs                       x86_64          1:2.3-2.fc25                                 fedora-multimedia          1.7 M
Paquets ignorés suite à des dépendances cassées:
 live555                         x86_64          1:2016.11.06-2.fc25                          fedora-multimedia          108 k

Résumé de la transaction
===============================================================================================================================
Installation   2 Paquets
Mettre à jour  5 Paquets
Ignorer        1 Paquet

Taille totale des téléchargements : 21 M
```

It is not expected for me, i miss something.

What should I do to update the system but keep vlc 2.x until I decided to move on 3.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not in front of a Fedora system at the moment but I think you can exclude one or more packages using the `--exclude` option:

```
$ sudo dnf update --exclude=<PACKAGE-NAME>
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answer with command-line option is obviously correct, but more appropriate solution is to write that into configuration file, so you don't have to think about it with every update. The file is `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`, where you should append:

```
exclude=vlc
```

Comment: I accepted other answer because you already have a lot of points! but i read and appreciated, thanks